# Cannot reach any websites on ubuntu.com domain over IPv4

Tags: apt, updates, ubuntu-website

Today, I am encountering problems with reaching any websites on ubuntu.com domain.

```
Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site.
We can’t connect to the server at ubuntu.com.
```

Also, I cannot download updates.

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease          
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease                 
  Temporary failure resolving 'nl.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'nl.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'nl.archive.ubuntu.com'
```

`status.canonical.com` does not load either (and other sites on canonical.com domain).

DNS resolution for ubuntu.com:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
ubuntu.com.     18  IN  A   91.189.88.181
ubuntu.com.     18  IN  A   91.189.88.180
```

Bit these addresses don't ping.

**Update**

After a reboot, I was able to open `ubuntu.com` in Firefox, and was able to run `apt update`. However, pinging `ubuntu.com` still did nit work. It appears now that `ubuntu.com` is reachable via IPv6 but not IPv4.

```
$ dig a ubuntu.com
<...>
;; ANSWER SECTION:
ubuntu.com.     51  IN  A   91.189.88.181
ubuntu.com.     51  IN  A   91.189.88.180
<...>
$ ping 91.189.88.181
PING 91.189.88.181 (91.189.88.181) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 91.189.88.181 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4076ms
$ tracepath 91.189.88.181
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1500
 1:  _gateway                                              4.869ms 
 1:  _gateway                                              3.077ms 
 2:  no reply
 3:  gv-rc0011-cr101-et119-201.core.as33915.net           20.414ms 
 4:  asd-rc0001-cr101-be156-10.core.as9143.net            15.348ms 
 5:  nl-srk03a-ri1-ae50-0.core.as9143.net                 14.500ms 
 6:  213.46.182.142                                       15.869ms asymm  7 
 7:  ae-2-3210.edge3.London1.Level3.net                   22.430ms asymm  9 
 8:  no reply
 9:  no reply
10:  no reply
11:  no reply
12:  no reply
13:  no reply
14:  no reply
```

However, if I use IPv6:

```
$ dig aaaa ubuntu.com
;; ANSWER SECTION:
ubuntu.com.     44  IN  AAAA    2001:67c:1360:8001::2c
ubuntu.com.     44  IN  AAAA    2001:67c:1360:8001::2b

$ ping 2001:67c:1360:8001::2c
PING 2001:67c:1360:8001::2c(2001:67c:1360:8001::2c) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2001:67c:1360:8001::2c: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=21.9 ms
64 bytes from 2001:67c:1360:8001::2c: icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=23.7 ms
64 bytes from 2001:67c:1360:8001::2c: icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=24.3 ms
64 bytes from 2001:67c:1360:8001::2c: icmp_seq=4 ttl=54 time=23.3 ms
^C
--- 2001:67c:1360:8001::2c ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3006ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 21.873/23.277/24.251/0.876 ms
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add the outputs of `traceroute ubuntu.com` and / or `mtr -r ubuntu.com`?

Comment: The problem resolved itself after a reboot. I still don't know what it was.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli In fact, the problem still partially remains. I can reach Ubuntu.com by IPv6 but not IPv4. See update.

Comment: If IPv4 for this address is not reachable _consistently_, you can talk to your ISP, because the resolved IPv4 seems to be correct. My `traceroute` or `tracepath 91.189.88.181` command successfully reaches `davybones.canonical.com`